# Check empty array before check checkbox

Tags: php, arrays

I use an array to get a checkbox list and the code below to get active options flagging respective checkbox (checked):

```
echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="user_company[]" value="' . $company_id . '"' .   (in_array($company_id, $bar) ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . '"/><label><b>' . $company_nome ."</b>, ". $company_das . " / " . $company_state . "</b><label></td></tr>";
```

All seems to work correctly, but if I have an Empty Array, I see this Warning:

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

How can I check if my array is empty before hitting this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function:

```
if(!empty($arr)) {
    echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="user_company[]" value="' . $company_id . '"' .   (in_array($company_id, $bar) ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . '"/><label><b>' . $company_nome ."</b>, ". $company_das . " / " . $company_state . "</b><label></td></tr>";
}
```